# Escribir 2 valores en un 1er scanf y el 2do scanf no sea saltado en C

Tags: c, scanf

Si en el primer scanf coloco dos valores ejemplo "Marco Antonio" separados por un espacio  automáticamente el 2do scanf no me pregunta nada y me toma como valor introducido el "Antonio".

¿Como hago para por lo menos evitar eso?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    system("clear");
    
    char apellido[30], 
         nombre[30];

    printf("Nombre: ");
    scanf("%30s", nombre);
    printf("Apellido: ");
    scanf("%30s", apellido);

    printf("Mi nombre es %s y mi apellido es %s. \n", nombre, apellido);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Si pones el `;` que falta, [el programa funciona perfectamente](https://tio.run/##dY7dCoJAEIXv9ykGQ1AwEbzLCHqAeoHqYl3XHFhX2V0DiZ7d1vUHKpqBufhmzjnDtkxQeR@GDUomuoLDXpsCm7g6kA8kMB8ZQWmgpiiDR4NFSJ4EbOleG14HHhOcKi/MHHSDVVQBbbkQWDSXNLlFE3clmzpXfKQZcbRV1r4MvLNb7GCx0oxKi/000V40y@bVIjnOGf9Eyw/hV9QJZz/gGnwNPdS4Hk8shqtcY3@dFDedkpBk5DUMLTW2SanQzjc "C (clang) – Try It Online") ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Por responder con la misma diligencia y amabilidad a tu comentario: Si no entiendo la pregunta, no la estás redactando bien. De todos modos de nada.

Answer (score 4):

Cambia la lectura mediante `scanf` por una lectura mediante `fgets`:

```
printf("Nombre: ");
fgets(nombre, 30, stdin);
printf("Apellido: ");
fgets(apellido, 30, stdin);
```

Ten en cuenta que también te leerá el carácter de final de salto de línea.

Comment: Muchas gracias Sr  PaperBirdMaster

Answer (score 4):

La entrada estándar en C funciona de la siguiente manera:

- La entrada es bloqueante, es decir, el programa se detiene hasta que hay algo que leer.
- Se entiende que hay algo que leer cuando en el buffer de entrada se introduce un salto de línea.

Lo que sucede en este código es que, ante la entrada `"Marco Antonio\n"` el programa no sale del primer `scanf` hasta que no se ha introducido el salto de línea... entonces empieza a leer y procesa la primera palabra `"Marco"`, después le llega el turno al segundo `scanf` que ve que sigue habiendo contenido en el buffer... y es cuando procesa la segunda palabra `"Antonio"` y elimina el salto de línea, por lo que un tercer `scanf` se quedaría esperando a que el usuario introdujese nuevos valores.

> ¿Como hago para por lo menos evitar eso?

Pues depende:

- Si tu idea es que tanto el nombre como el apellido puedan tener espacios tendrás que configurar `scanf` de forma diferente:

  ```
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", nombre);
  ```

  De esta forma `scanf` no se detendrá en el primer espacio sino en el salto de línea. La explicación a esa entrada es la siguiente:

  - `%[^\n]` indica a `scanf` que debe leer hasta encontrar un salto de línea
  - `%*c` esta opción lee un único caracter (el salto de linea). El asterisco indica a `scanf` que debe descartar dicho caracter.
- Si tu idea es descartar la segunda palabra, tendrás que vaciar el buffer de entrada a mano. No hay una forma estándar de realizar esto, pero una de las más utilizadas es la siguiente:

  ```
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
  ```

  Introduce estas lineas **después** de tu `scanf` y así descartarás todo lo que haya en el buffer de entrada hasta el primer salto de línea (que también se descartará)

Comment: En verdad Gracias Sr eferion, ese trozo de código "scanf("%[^\n]%*c", nombre);" no solo me soluciono el problema sino que me permite introducir varios texto eso acompañado de la explicación para no hacerlo mecánicamente sin entenderr cual es la vuelta. Un 1.000.000 de gracias.

Comment: @plazamarco Me alegra que la respuesta te haya servido. No obstante, no está de más votar las respuestas que te hayan ayudado y marcar como solución aquella que mejor te vino para resolver el problema.